# Call to undefined method Spatie\PdfToImage\Pdf::setCompressionQuality()

Tags: laravel

I get the the error below when trying to compress a converted image in Laravel using the spatie/pdf-to-image package

> Call to undefined method Spatie\PdfToImage\Pdf::setCompressionQuality()

My code is as below.

```
use Spatie\PdfToImage\Pdf; // use statement is declared at the top of the file

$pdf = new Pdf($file->getRealPath());
$pdf->setCompressionQuality(75);
$pdf->saveImage($storagePath . 'public/files/flipbooks/' . $savedFileName);
```

Comment: What if you do "new Spatie\PdfToImage\Pdf", instead of "new Pdf" just to make sure you are instantiating the correct Pdf class

Comment: @bumperbox the error message lists the correct class

Comment: @bumperbox  I have declared a use statement at top of file: use Spatie\PdfToImage\Pdf; Have updated the question to reflect this.